# how can I apply css based on parent div class

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 div blocks similar to each other except their additional class. one have `desktop_version` and second have `mobile_version` class. now how I can apply css to child div of a div which have class with `mobile_version`. I am trying to achieve responsive design in doing so

### mobileVersion

```
<div id="contactNumber_Wrapper" class="mobileVersion">

                    <div class="contact-number">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <span>+44 02078062629</span>
                        <span class="outer-strip"></span>
                    </div>
</div>
```

### desktop-version

```
<div id="contactNumber_Wrapper" class="desktop_version">

                <div class="contact-number">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <span>+44 02078062629</span>
                    <span class="outer-strip"></span>
                </div>

</div>
```

### css

??????

Comment: Do you mean this? '.mobileVersion .contact-number { css code }'

Comment: Use both like this:- `.mobileVersion .contact-number {}` and `.desktop_version .contact-number{}`.

Comment: Simple, mobile: `.mobileVersion .contact-number` non-mobile:`.desktop_version .contact-number`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By aggregating the classes in CSS:

For mobile:

```
.mobileVersion .contact-number{
    color:#444;
}
```

For desktop:

```
.desktop_version .contact-number{
    color:#333;
}
```

---

Note: You can join as many as you wish eg.

```
.mobileVersion .contact-number .fa fa-phone {
    //some css properties
}
```

and with `div id's` :

```
#contactNumber_Wrapper .mobileVersion .contact-number .fa fa-phone {
    //some css properties
}
```

Comment: what about apply css to #contactNumber_Wrapper with class .mobileVersion or other way around

Comment: same rule `#contactNumber_Wrapper .contact-number` , note that `divs` starts with `#` and classes with `.`

Comment: @Urahara, divs don't start with `#`, ID's do

Answer (score 3):

What your talking about is **Descendant selectors/combinators**

From [W3C selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

---

### 8.1. Descendant combinator

> At times, authors may want selectors to describe an element that is
>   the descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "an EM
>   element that is contained within an H1 element"). Descendant
>   combinators express such a relationship. A descendant combinator is
>   whitespace that separates two sequences of simple selectors. A
>   selector of the form "A B" represents an element B that is an
>   arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> For example, consider the following selector:

```
h1 em
```

> It represents an em element being the descendant of an h1 element. It
>   is a correct and valid, but partial, description of the following
>   fragment:

```
<h1>This <span class="myclass">headline
is <em>very</em> important</span></h1>
```

> The following selector:

```
div * p
```

> represents a p element that is a grandchild or later descendant of a
>   div element. Note the whitespace on either side of the "*" is not part
>   of the universal selector; the whitespace is a combinator indicating
>   that the div must be the ancestor of some element, and that that
>   element must be an ancestor of the p.
>
> The following selector, which combines descendant combinators and
>   attribute selectors, represents an element that (1) has the href
>   attribute set and (2) is inside a p that is itself inside a div:

```
div p *[href]
```

---

### TL;DR

mobile: `.mobileVersion .contact-number` non-mobile:`.desktop_version .contact-number`

Comment: That's the old spec. The current spec is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) and they've been renamed. The question is actually asking about child combinators though (although a descendant combinator will work). Please use the quote formatting option in the Stackoverflow editor too so that it is clear what content is original and what is quoted.

Comment: Updated to latest spec, ta @Quentin

Comment: The quote knackered up the code formatting so I choose the lesser of two evils...unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
.mobileVersion .contact-number {
//your style
} 
.desktop_version .contact-number{
//your style
}
```